# how to print a single element of list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

I'm a beginner preparing myself for me exams , I need a little help and I know this is the best place where I can get help from. I have written a small code which is

```
for i in range (days)
day=[]
day.append('monday')
day.append('tuesday')
print()
```

I need to know if i only want to print monday which is the first element of list what will be the code for it. I tried day.i(1) but it does not work can you please help me out with it. The code is in python.
Thank you.

Comment: The code you've currently given isn't even runnable. You should edit this question and provide a functional example. Despite that, you should google for a Python tutorial and read through it, that will help you in the long run.

Comment: You should be able to find out the answer in any basic python tutorials. It is a basic data structure used in python and is knows as `list`. You can access the list elements by using `list indexes` which starts from *0*.

Comment: [I suggest you read the documentation or preferably some kind of Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
days=[]
days.append("Monday ")
days.append(" Tuesday")
print days[0]
```

## days[0] is the index position of your first element. (I.e, "Monday")

Comment: `print days[0]` isn't valid Python 3. Besides that, you've simply repeated already existing information.

Comment: Tq for letting me know this bro

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you want this:

```
day=[]
day.append('monday')
day.append('tuesday')
for i in range(day):
    print(day[i])
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a more simpler code.

```
weekdays = []
weekdays.append('monday')
weekdays.append('tuesday')
weekdays[0] ## First element of the list will be printed
weekdays[1] ## Second element of the list will be printed
```

Edit : Sorry, I had to edit this answer two times. It was written in a hurry. Besides this is the first answer I am ever posting.

Comment: No, don't use `list` as a name.

Comment: Your comments are wrong, `weekdays[1]` does not print the first element, it prints the second. Same for `weekdays[2]`, which is also out of range as mentioned. Index starts at 0, not 1.

Comment: Furthermore, this doesn't print anything unless you run it in REPL/ iPython